# Cropperjs fixed cropping area height/width to crop image

Tags: javascript, cropperjs

I'm using cropper.js on MVC 5 Razor page where i do not want user to select cropping area with mouse, I want to initialize cropper object with predefined clipping (selected) area that user can't resize, but user can move clipping area on the picture to crop a part of picture.

I was not able to find any option to disable clipping, i checked on their Git [page](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs) and it looks like it does not have ability,  moreover i posted my request on Git [page](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/issues/582) but did not get any response. i need help how can i workaround to achieve this.

```js
        window.onload = function() {

            var Cropper = window.Cropper;
            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var container = document.querySelector('.img-container');
            var image = container.getElementsByTagName('img').item(0);
            var download = ''; 
            var actions = document.getElementById('actions');
            var dataX = 128; 
            var dataY = 72; 
            var dataHeight = 1024; 
            var dataWidth = 576; 
            var dataRotate = 0;  
            var dataScaleX = -1; 
            var dataScaleY = 1;  
            var options = {
                aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                preview: '.img-preview',
                ready: function (e) {
                    console.log(e.type);
                },
                cropstart: function (e) {
                    console.log(e.type, e.detail.action);
                },
                cropmove: function (e) {
                    console.log(e.type, e.detail.action);
                },
                cropend: function (e) {
                    console.log(e.type, e.detail.action);
                },
                crop: function (e) {
                    var data = e.detail;

                    console.log(e.type);
                    dataX.value = Math.round(data.x);
                    dataY.value = Math.round(data.y);
                    dataHeight.value = Math.round(data.height);
                    dataWidth.value = Math.round(data.width);
                    dataRotate.value = typeof data.rotate !== 'undefined' ? data.rotate : '';
                    dataScaleX.value = typeof data.scaleX !== 'undefined' ? data.scaleX : '';
                    dataScaleY.value = typeof data.scaleY !== 'undefined' ? data.scaleY : '';
                },
                zoom: function (e) {
                    console.log(e.type, e.detail.ratio);
                }
            };

            var cropper = new Cropper(image, options);
        }
```

```css
    .img-container {
        min-height: 497px;
        max-width: 497px;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        background-color: white;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .img-container > img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    img {
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-style: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.5/cropper.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.5/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/266011/pexels-photo-266011.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" id="croppr" />
</div>
```

Comment: There's literally [an example](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/examples/fixed-crop-box.html) of what you're describing right on the site bud.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, though in example i can move the image not cropping area but good to have this functionality, not sure why i could not find this example on site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With reference to help by @Chris W. I was able to setup with fixed clipping area.

```js
        var image = document.getElementById('croppr');
        var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
            dragMode: 'move',
            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
            autoCropArea: 0.65,
            restore: false,
            guides: false,
            center: false,
            highlight: false,
            cropBoxMovable: true,
            cropBoxResizable: false,
            toggleDragModeOnDblclick: false,
        });
```

```css
    .img-container {
        min-height: 497px;
        max-width: 497px;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        background-color: white;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .img-container > img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    img {
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-style: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.5/cropper.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.5/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/266011/pexels-photo-266011.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" id="croppr" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

CSS

```
.cropped-img-container {
    width: 100%;
}

.cropped-img-container>img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.object-fit-contain {
    object-fit: contain !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="cropped-img-container text-center">
    <img id="cropped-image" src="path_of_your_image" class="w-100 object-fit-contain" height="500" />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this solve my problem

```
minContainerHeight: height,
minContainerWidth: width,
minCanvasHeight: height,
minCanvasWidth: width,
```

or

```
        minContainerHeight="400"
        minContainerWidth="400"
        minCanvasHeight="400"
        minCanvasWidth="400"
```